# Help with the proof of Max Noether's Residue Theorem from Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm having problems understanding one part of the proof of the Residue Theorem, on chapter 8 of Fulton's book Algebraic Curves, section 8.1 (http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf page 98) There is a lot of notation, because it came from another propositions. But the Residue Theorem is the following:

Let $C,E$ be as above. Suppose $D$ and $D'$ are effective divisors
on X, with $D' = D$. Suppose $G$ is an adjoint of degree $m$ such that $div(G)=D+E+A$,
for some effective divisor $A$. Then there is an adjoint $G'$ of degreem such that $div(G')=D'+ E + A$.

Proof. Let $H,H'$ be curves of the same degree such that $D+div(H)=D'+div(H')$.
Then $div(GH)= div(H')+D´+E+ A \geq div(H')+E$. Let $F$ be the form defining $C$.
Applying the criterion of Proposition 3 of §7.5 to $F, H'$, and $GH$,we see thatNoether’s
conditions are satisfied at all $P\in C$. By Noether’s theorem,$GH = F'F+G'H'$ for some
$F',G'$,where $deg(G')=m$. Then $\textbf{div(G')=div(GH)-div(H')}=D'+E+A$, as desired.
Is the first equality of the last part, the one I don't understand..

I've understood all of it, but can't figure out why  $Div(F)=0$

I'll appreciate any suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: What are $G$, $H$, $G'$, and $H'$?

Answer (score 3):

The equality holds because the divisors are defined in terms of the local rings of the curve $C$. Since $F$ is the form defining $C$, its residue is zero in the coordinate ring and the local rings of the curve. Hence,

$$ 
\text{div}(F'F + G'H') = \text{div}(G'H')
$$